# Macbook Optimised battery charging not working with third party Charger

Tags: macbook-pro, power

Since I've been using a new third party charger (65W) to charge my MBP, it always charges past 80% and it always is at 100%. Why doesn't optimised battery charging work with the third party power supply?

Here's the charger I'm using: https://www.hama.com/00210592/hama-gan-charger-usb-c-power-delivery-pd-+-usb-a-qualcomm-30-65w-white

Comment: What kind of power supply?

Comment: https://www.hama.com/00210592/hama-gan-charger-usb-c-power-delivery-pd-+-usb-a-qualcomm-30-65w-white